# Reading a json file using Gson in play framework

Tags: jquery, playframework, datatables

I'm using Play framework, I want to read a json file, I have a json file with contents similar to

> {"columns_map":["SenderName","Message","Device","Acknowledge","Time"],"rows_map":{"219":["mahesh","come soon","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1","Data Inserted Successfully",""]}}
>
> SenderName,Message, Device,Acknowledge,Time will be columns for JQuery datatable, rows_map will be the records, I can't feed the file directly to JQuery since i have to perform conditions and display a certain records.

There will be 5 lakh records inside the file. Is it best to gson or other parser(which one please?) or create own encoder/decoder functionality
How to parse the file so that i can feed the datatable as i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Using gson should work.  Just `import com.google.gson.*`

Those files are already included with Play!

Comment: i have imported the files and i'm able do the simple example. but i don't know how to do for my case. Number of Columns, and name of the columns will also be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

GSON parser is fast and efficient. You can use Play jobs to process this large json file (of 5 lakh recs) and after processing cache this file on the file-system.

From the front-end, use ajax to retrieve - only the required number of records that would be displayed on the table in the browser. The play controller handling this ajax call should retrieve the cached json file and render the json. This also should keep track of the record pointer - kind of custom pagination

Comment: I just want to use gson, but i can't find a way for my case. The columns will be dynamic but in gson the data class should define the columns which is predefined. In my case it's not predefined.

Comment: Then use [Jackson library](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). Get the key values in the collection (Java Map) and manipulate this map according to your needs. You could also look at the Jackson Streaming API example.